# Recursive function does not work without saving parameter

Tags: c, recursion

I have a recursive function which runs through a quadtree and generates for each node a key. But this only works when I save the variable `myKey` as `myKey1`. If I do not do that, the resulting keys are wrong. But why? That is not clear to me.

Here is the function:

```
void keygen(tree *tn, long unsigned int myKey)
{
    long unsigned int myKey1 = myKey; // Why do I need this line?

    for(int q=0; q<4; q++){
        // 1) Check if child exists
        if(tn->child[q] != NULL){
            // Make key
            myKey1 = (myKey<<DIM)|q;
            // Save key
            tn->child[q]->key = myKey1;
            // Call again if leaf               
            if(tn -> child[q] -> isLeaf == 0){ 
                keygen(tn->child[q], myKey1);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Because of the line `myKey1 = (myKey<<DIM)|q;`?  If you were originally using myKey on the left and right, you'd be accumulating shifts on every iteration of the loop.

Comment: @happydave: Why not make this an answer?

Comment: @happydave Yes, now I see it. You are totally right! Thank you!

Comment: @alk: Mostly because I didn't have time to read the code carefully enough to be confident that this was the real issue.  I guess I'll turn it into an answer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is likely the issue

```
myKey1 = (myKey<<DIM)|q;
```

If you don't make a separate myKey1 variable, then you'll be shifting by DIM on every iteration of the loop, so by the fourth iteration, you'll have shifted by 4*DIM (and bitwise-ORed with various values of q between shifts).

It seems like your intent is to just shift and or once relative to the original key, which is what you accomplish by creating a new variable rather than modifying the original myKey in place.